# How to do "See Also" to a book using doxygen

Tags: doxygen

The Javadoc `@see` allows a simple string as an argument to refer to something like a book, e.g.:

```
@see "The Java Programming Language."
```

As far as I can tell, the Doxygen `\see` offers no equivalent.  Is there any way to have a book reference generated in the documentation, e.g.:

> **See Also**
>    *The C++ Programming Language*, Bjarne Stroustrup, Addison-Wesley, 2000, section 19.4.1: *The Standard Allocator*

?

## Clarification

This question is about how to do a "See Also" as part of a comment, e.g.:

```
/**
 * Allocates memory in an amazing way.
 * \param size The number of bytes to allocate.
 * \return Returns a pointer to the start of the allocated memory.
 * \see MyOtherClass::alloc()
 * \see "The C++ Programming Language," Bjarne Stroustrup, Addison-Wesley, 2000,
 * section 19.4.1: The Standard Allocator.
 */
void* my_alloc( size_t size );
```

Of course the above does ***not*** work in Doxygen.  Note that if there are multiple `\see` tags, they should be merged into a single "See Also" section (like the way `\see` normally works.

Comment: Why does the example documentation block not work? It should based on Dimitriy's answer. Perhaps you can explain why in the question.

Comment: Nowadays one can use BibTex to give references

Answer (score 5):

Whilst, I am a bit late to this, hopefully the following is helpful.

You can in fact use a string with the [`\see`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdsee) command (which is included for compatibility with Javadoc and is simply an aliases to [`\sa`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdsa)), as Dmitriy has shown, even if this is undocumented.

Alternatively, and perhaps more properly, you could try using the [`\cite`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcite) command to add a bibliographic reference .

Finally, you state that

> Note that if there are multiple \see tags, they should be merged into a single "See Also" section (like the way \see normally works[)].

Doxygen does merge multiple `\see`'s and `\sa`'s together as Dmitriy demonstrates. However, in the comments to Dmitriy's answer, you state that

> I never claimed that Doxygen doesn't merges multiple \see together: I said that if I were to define my own tag, it wouldn't merge that together with `\see` since it would be my own tag and not a `\see`.

It is possible to define your own tag and have it merged into the "See also" section if your tag is an aliases to `\sa`.

Answer (score 4):

I tried multiple \see in my project and doxygen merges it into single "See also" section:

```
/// \see MyOtherClass::alloc()
/// \see "The C++ Programming Language," Bjarne Stroustrup, Addison-Wesley, 2000,
/// \see 3
/// \see 4
```

Output is:

**See also:**
    MyOtherClass::alloc()
    "The C++ Programming Language," Bjarne Stroustrup, Addison-Wesley, 2000,
    3
    4

Are you using latest version of doxygen?

Comment: I never claimed that Doxygen doesn't merges multiple \see together: I said that if I were to define my own tag, it wouldn't merge *that* together with \see since it would be my own tag and not a \see.  Your example shows an undocumented way to use \see with a string (your second line).

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about styling, you can define your own tag with [`ALIASES`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_aliases) configuration option.

If your question is about creating a bibliography page, you can define a specific cross reference tag, using [`\xrefitem`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdxrefitem) tag.

Of course, you can combine both.

If your question is about handling a bibliography database, ala EndNote or BibTeX, I'm afraid Doxygen is not the best tool.

Comment: Defining my own tag wouldn't "auto merge" with other \see tags.  This is not about creating a bibliography page nor database.

Comment: Nowadays one can use BibTex to give references.